# Lookup check between dates

Tags: vba, excel

I need VBA code for lookup function which checks if some value is between two dates. My question is how to write this "2;1/" in VBA?

```
=LOOKUP(2;1/((J3>=Sheet2!$B$2:$B$25)*J3<=Sheet2!$C$2:$C$25));Sheet2!$F$2:$F$25)
```

Can I write something like?:

```
abc=application.Lookup(2;1/((Cells(3,10)>=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(B2:B25)*Cells(3,10)<=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(C2:C25));Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(F2:F25)
```

Comment: Replace `;` with `,`. Comma is that what you need.

Comment: Maciej Los, please see my edition of a comment.

Comment: Maybe this is a better solution..but it throws me a zero... 'abc = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(rng3, rng1, "<=" & the_date, rng2, ">=" & the_date)'

Comment: replace ; with , and everything and ranges must be in quotes range("b2:b25")

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the `;` is the default separator in Serbia so that should be fine.
Your brackets on the other hand are in the wrong place - the opening bracket closes before the last `;` and the final closing bracket has no accompanying opening bracket.

To write in VBA you can use:

Using the sheet codename:

```
r = Application.WorksheetFunction.Lookup _
        (2; 1 / (J3 >= Sheet2.Range("$B$2:$B$25")) * J3 <= Sheet2.Range("$C$2:$C$25"); Sheet2.Range("$F$2:$F$25"))
```

Using the sheet tab name:

```
r = Application.WorksheetFunction.Lookup _
        (2; 1 / (J3 >= Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("$B$2:$B$25")) * J3 <= Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("$C$2:$C$25"); Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("$F$2:$F$25"))
```

Add the ranges to variables and using them:

```
Dim MyRange1 As Range
Dim MyRange2 As Range
Dim MyRange3 As Range
MyRange1 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("$B$2:$B$25")
MyRange2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("$C$2:$C$25")
MyRange3 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("$F$2:$F$25")

r = Application.WorksheetFunction.Lookup _
        (2; 1 / (J3 >= MyRange1) * J3 <= MyRange2; MyRange3)
```

I've not really used LookUp, so can't say whether the formula will return the results you expect.